# Can we handle network failure in the event of form.submit to a different site?

Tags: javascript, http, form-submit

Assume there is an SPA which has a button called "Go To Some Other Site" whose ajax response is a simple HTML that has a form which can submit to a different site.

```
<form action="www.someothersite.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Will the `form.submit` destroy the current DOM immediately and redirect to other site causing my site's Javascript to be destroyed? Or will it possible for me to handle a network failure in my site's Javascript and abort the submit in any way?

PS: I am assuming this is a not an Ajax Request. Due to security reasons I can't do an Ajax.

Comment: No you cannot handle this without using AJAX/Javascript. Your submit issues a HTTP post, if this returns a re-direct the browser will re-direct. You can't interfere with how a browser processes HTTP

Comment: Please let me know if this belongs to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A form POST request is still a HTTP requst and all AJAX requests are HTTP requests. So the solution would be to use AJAX to submit the form manually instead of relying on the base form handler. That way you get full control over the error handling.

Comment: So "if this returns" can't be handled? That is my question. Also please move this as an answer!

Comment: Once the POST is sent, its out of your domain. There is nothing to handle.